# Nginx: Redirect IP address to domain name

Tags: nginx, redirect

With the following Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name isitmaintained.com;

    ...
}

server {
    listen 178.62.136.230:80;
    server_name 178.62.136.230;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

    return 301 $scheme://isitmaintained.com$request_uri;
}
```

I am trying to redirect `http://178.62.136.230/` to http://isitmaintained.com/ but when I deploy this config I end up with a `Redirect loop` or both of those links.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this on the second block:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 178.62.136.230;

    return 302 $scheme://google.com$request_uri;
}
```

The problem is that the second server block `listen` directive is more specific than first server block, therefore it is always used. And since the second block is the only virtual host for that `listen` specification, it is always used.

Note : 301 will add permanent redirect. Use 302 for testing.

Comment: That makes sense. But when I apply this, I get the following error: `nginx: [emerg] could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32` :( And that doesn't make sense because my domain name is not that long.

Comment: Well, for some reason your set up requires more storage space for the virtual host server names in nginx, so you should just increase the setting.

Comment: My apologies for not trying directly, I was sure there was something wrong. But you were right, the redirection works now! A very warm thank you :)

Comment: you are F***** right man , solved a problem of mine , upvoted , thnx

Answer (score 3):

You were close. Its rewrite that you are looking for.

```
server {
    listen 178.62.136.230:80;
    server_name 178.62.136.230 isitmaintained.com;

    rewrite  ^/(.*)$  http://www.isitmaintained.com/$1 permanent;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.isitmaintained.com;
    # Serve Stuff Here.
}
```

Comment: This `rewrite` and `return` above do exactly the same thing.